# Align one div to the bottom of an image in all screen sizes, regardless of lines of text

Tags: html, css

I've encountered an issue with aligning a div at the bottom of an image. The div contains a p tag which can have 1 or more lines of text depending on how long the sentence is and what the screen size is. Ideally, I want the div with the p tag to always be set against the bottom edge of the image it's on top of regardless of what is in the p tag and what screen size is currently used. The problem is that, when more text is present in the p tag, the height of the div extends down past the image. I've tried using margin-top but that's not reliable responsively. Is there a way to accomplish the task of keeping a div consistently at the bottom of an image regardless of the content of said div?

Here is the html setup for what I have:

```
<div class="Sub-Banner-Container Right-Sub-Banner clearfix">
   <div class="Banner-Image-Container clearfix" style="background-image: url('/img/Banner-Image-Left.jpg')">
      <div class="Sub-Banner-Inner clearfix">
         <h1 class="Sub-Banner-Headline Right-Headline Dark-Text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
          <div class="Sub-Banner-Overlay Right-Overlay clearfix">
              <p class="Sub-Banner-Sub-Headline Dark-Text">Maecenas at pellentesque quam, eget placerat nisi. Fusce eu urna arcu. Ut consequat eros eu metus accumsan elementum.</p>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The div Sub-Banner-Overlay has a transparent background color and contains the p tag Sub-Banner-Sub-Headline which could contain any number of characters. The div Banner-Image-Container contains the image that I want to keep the Sub-Banner-Overlay within.

Some CSS:

```
.Sub-Banner-Container {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    min-width: 0;
    @include breakpoint(830px) {
        padding: 20px;
        height: auto;
    }
    @include breakpoint(540px) {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .Banner-Image-Container {
        float: none;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        clear: none;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 1040px;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-size: cover;
        min-width: 0;
        background-position: 50% 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
        @include breakpoint(1060px) {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: none;
        }
        @include breakpoint(540px) {
            background-position: 100% 0;
        }
        .Sub-Banner-Inner {
            float: none;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            clear: none;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 0;
            @include breakpoint(1060px) {
                max-width: none;
            }
            @include breakpoint(650px) {
                height: 235px;
            }
            @include breakpoint(540px) {
                height: 350px;
            }
            @include breakpoint(460px) {
                height: 300px;
            }
            @include breakpoint(380px) {
                height: 251px;
            }
            .Sub-Banner-Overlay {
                float: none;
                height: 100px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-top: 242px;
                clear: none;
                width: 100%;
                background: rgba($box-shadow,.65);
                margin-right: auto;
                min-width: 0;
                display: table;
                @include breakpoint(650px) {
                    margin-top: 150px;
                }
                @include breakpoint(572px) {
                    margin-top: 125px;
                }
                @include breakpoint(540px) {
                    margin-top: 240px;
                }
                @include breakpoint(460px) {
                    margin-top: 189px;
                }
                @include breakpoint(427px) {
                    margin-top: 165px;
                }
                @include breakpoint(380px) {
                    margin-top: 117px;
                }
                @include breakpoint(331px) {
                    margin-top: 90px;
                }
                .Sub-Banner-Sub-Headline {
                    float: none;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    width: 99.808061%;
                    text-align: left;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    line-height: normal;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    clear: none;
                    min-height: 0;
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    min-width: 0;
                    padding: 16px 20px;
                    opacity: 1;
                    z-index: 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS related to this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a combination of `position:relative;` on your image container and `position:absolute;` on your text container. Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvenabl/j376shch/embedded/result/).

No matter the height of the image, your text will be absolutely positioned to the bottom of your image container.

Comment: I think the issue with this example is that the image has to be able to be controlled by the user. Hardcoding the url of an image into the CSS won't work as the image could be any image.

Comment: I suppose I saw the inline style and figured it would have the same affect, but yes I think you are right. I created a [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvenabl/g5dc77gc/2/) that accounts for placing an image element without CSS.

Comment: This is the route I ended up taking to get things working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the `div.image` with your image, this should work. The div container should increase in height and move upwards rather than break outside of the image container.

It's hard to say without looking at your CSS, but this simple example shows what your asking for in basic terms.

```css
.image{background:#CCC;height:400px;position:relative;width:400px}
.content{background:#999;position:absolute;bottom:0;width:80%}
p{font-size:14px;padding:5px}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ispum dolor Lorem ispum dolor Lorem ispum dolor Lorem ispum dolor Lorem ispum dolor Lorem ispum dolor Lorem ispum dolor Lorem ispum dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```